# Advice on Profile Picture System (Rails 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, rubygems

Just looking for some advice on the best to approach a profile picture system in a rails 3 app. I want to host pictures on cloudfront, so if anyone has any advice or tips its greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your best bet is probably [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip). If you check out the README on the GitHub page it'll walk you through how to configure it within your User model, and display the attachments (or avatars) within your views.

(Linked from Paperclip's Wiki) [Using Amazon’s CloudFront with Rails & Paperclip](http://blog.tristanmedia.com/2009/09/using-amazons-cloudfront-with-rails-and-paperclip/)